# Disable syntax highlighting for text files (*.txt) in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open text files (".txt" plaintext files), in Visual Studio Code, they are syntax highlighted and also vscode starts offering suggestions as I type. How can I turn all this off and just use vscode as a simple editor for these files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how to fix it:

1. Open a text file.
2. In the lower right corner of the window, click the syntax highlighting language (in my case, `C++`):
   [image]
3. A menu will appear at the top center of the window. Click `Configure File Association for '.txt'...`:
   [image]
4. A list of languages will appear. Scroll down and choose `Plain Text`.
5. Now ".txt" files will be treated as plaintext and won't be highlighted, etc.